# Loop though Children elements , Find something and access its sibling property

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a `WrapPanel` which contains some Images (thumbnails).

When the user press Left or Right arrow key, I want to show the next/previous image.

```
private void frmMain_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        int j = 0;
        foreach (Image child in WrapPanelPictures.Children)
        {
            if (child.Source == MainPic.Source)
            {
                MainPic.Source = WrapPanelPictures.Children[j + 1].Source;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I tried a LINQ approach, but I'm a beginner with LINQ.

```
var imgfound = from r in WrapPanelPictures.Children.OfType<Image>()
               where r.Source == MainPic.Source
               select r;
MessageBox.Show(imgfound.Source.ToString());
```

imgfound is supposed to be a list, right? maybe that's why I can't access Source property. Anyway this return the current Image shown. I want the sibling.

**UPDATE**:
Well I made a workaround as for now. But still waiting for a proper solution.

I created a ListBox and added all WrapPanel Childrens to it. Then used the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` properties to select the previous and next items.

Comment: how do you determine the start point (CurrentImage) for your next and previous?

Comment: @WiiMaxx The source of `MainPic` determines the picture which is currently showing. Pressing right and left arrow keys is supposed to change the current picture. I think I should point/link the thumbnail pic and the current picture showing together. Since I can't do that (yet), I got to loop through all WrapPanel Childrens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WrapPanelPictures.Children[j + 1].Source` cannot work since you are trying to access the `Source` property of `UIElement` which does not exist. You should cast the `UIElement` to Image before accessing the `Source`:

```
MainPic.Source = (WrapPanelPictures.Children[j + 1] as Image).Source;
```

I am sure there are more elegant solutions to obtain the same results.

Comment: This is working :) Exactly what I was looking for. And  you're right. There should be better solutions to achieve this. But this was the closest approach I could think of. Just imagine you have a WrapPanel containing some thumbnails, and you want to navigate through them using the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You got your answer why you can't access the Source property by Novitchi. I would nevertheless like to suggest that you rethink your code.

The way I see it, you are in control of what your wrap panel displays. That means you should be able to store things like "all the images" and also the selected index in a field or property. Instead of parsing your wrap panel's children for images every time around and comparing image sources, you should know at any given time what your selected image or index is.

The code might then roughly look something like this:

```
private List<BitmapImage> _images;
private int _selectedIndex;

private void frmMain_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        _selectedIndex = (_selectedIndex + 1) % _images.Count;
        MainPic.Source = _images[_selectedIndex];
    }
}
```

If your UI is highly dynamic (drag/dropping images into the wrap panel or something like that), using Bindings to link your data with the UI is the way to go. In any case, I also strongly recommend considering a ViewModel pattern like MVVM.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I got your idea, creating a list of images before adding them in wrappanel, then set index to 0 and use the list to navigate,.... I wish I could share that repution bounty with you :D

Comment: No worries about the bounty, glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

use method `FindVisualChildren`. It traverses through Visual Tree and find your desired control.

This should do the trick

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
if (depObj != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
        {
            yield return (T)child;
        }

        foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
        {
            yield return childOfChild;
        }
    }
}
}
```

then you enumerate over the controls like so

```
foreach (TextBlock tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(window))
{
    // do something with tb here
}
```

Comment: I told you I want to call the object's (tb in this case) sibling property. not itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare `j` inside the foreach loop. Otherwise this will always show the image for `j=0` which is  `WrapPanelPictures.Children[1]`

```
    private void frmMain_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
           int j = 0;
           foreach (Image child in WrapPanelPictures.Children)
           {
                // int j = 0;
                if (child.Source == MainPic.Source)
                {
                    MainPic.Source = WrapPanelPictures.Children[j + 1].Source;
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok I fixed that part, But you missed the point. I am saying the Source property of `WrapPanelPictures.Children[j + 1].Source` isn't working.